# Using agent parameters from main to different agent?

Tags: anylogic

For a project I'm trying to select the right output if a parameter of the created agent is true. The agent is created in the main but goes into a different agent for the selection of the output. If I use a select in the main and use the statement for the parameter as condition it works fine. Whenever it enters the agent and I use the same statement it gives an error (Description: product1 cannot be resolved or is not a field. Location: testCase5/Transport/selectOutput - SelectOutput).

I tried using different conditions like main.agent.product1 . Can't seem to solve the issue. I know that it has to do something with declaration probably but I'm clueless at the moment.

//for the condition that works if I put the selectOutput in the main

agent.product1

//for the condition in the agent I tried the same but didn't work. also tried

main.agent.product1 // Gives the same error but for (Description: agentcannot be resolved or is not a field.)

(Main)agent.product1 
//And a few more

Comment: No the product agents is transported from the main to the selectOutput agent.
https://ibb.co/dQc2VPG
the first select ouput uses the condition agent.product5 and that works fine
https://ibb.co/v3XGCKg
as soon as a different product enters the transport agent it goes wrong.
https://ibb.co/b5Z6RsM

Comment: For each process flow, you have to define the Agent type, usually you that in the first block (Source or Enter) and then AnyLogic sets it automatically in all attached blocks. It might be that once you enter your custom block this "automatic" setting of the flowing Agent's type is not working. Have a look in all your flowchart blocks inside your custom block to check if the Agent type settings (under the tab "Advanced") are set to your specific Agent type (the one with the "product" variable)

Comment: You're a hero. That was it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AnyLogic each block of a project flow (regardless if from the process modeling library, the pedestrian library or another) has the type of Agent that is flowing through it defined in its properties. You can find this setting as *Agent type* in the block's properties under *Advanced*.

[image: block agent type definition]

If you fail to set this correctly (meaning this setting equals the type of Agents you let flow through it), it will still flow through, BUT: you cannot access the specific properties of the Agent type.

That said, usually you do not even have to think about, because AnyLogic has an automatism there: The first block of your process flow, typically a Source-block or a Enter-block is the only block where you have to make the correct setting, all attached blocks get it then automatically!

[image: source agent type settings]

However this does not work when:

- You have separate flows (eg. you leave one flow through an Exit-block and enter another by an Enter). You'll manually have to put the correct setting also for the first block of the second process flow.
- Your process flow is continued inside of another Agent/Custom Block, as in your example. AnyLogic doesnt realize the process flow inside your custom block is logically connected to the outside process flow in main. You have to specifiy manually again the Agent type flowing through in the first block of your process inside your Custom Block.